# Best practice for hiding API keys in a JS project?

Tags: javascript, security, api-key

I've got a chrome plugin project that sends a fetch request to [Unsplash's](https://unsplash.com/) API for a new background image every two minutes. In this request, I send an access key which is to remain a secret, but since it's sort of a 'webpage' anyone who knows web development or js would be able to find the access key.

**What is the best practice for restricting access to this kind of information (Read: API-Keys)?**

I have Google'd and most of the articles I found about it have some framework in the backend.

Comment: `What is the best practice for restricting access to this kind of information` don't send them to the browser

Comment: I have been thinking about making an API that sends the request for the browser extension (as mentioned in your link), but I was hoping there were other viable options.

Comment: There's simply no other option. Obfuscation can be defeated, and as long as the call is made from user's device, they can just listen to it.

Comment: SO has Q&A format. Let's keep it